# PHP merge multiple arrays comparing 3 keys and values

Tags: php, laravel

I have 5 multidimensional arrays that I want to merge together. All the different arrays have different lenght and each of the elements of the arrays have 4 keys and values, 3 of them are shared between the arrays. These 3 can be compared, and in the case that these 3 values match, then the arrays can be merged together.

As an example 3 of my arrays look like this:

```
array ( 0 => array("AccountID" => 9407, "year" => 2019,"month" => "November","received" => 36), 1 => array("AccountID" => 1975,"year" => 2019,"month" => "November","received" => 230),)
array ( 0 => array("AccountID" => 9407,"year" => 2019,"month" => "November","analyzed" => 138), 1 => array("AccountID" => 1975,"year" => 2019,"month" => "April","analyzed" => 1),)
array ( 0 => array("AccountID" => 9407,"year" => 2019,"month" => "November","failed" => 1), 1 => array("AccountID" => 1975,"year" => 2020,"month" => "April","failed" => 7),)
```

What I'm loooking for is something like this

```
^ array:11 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "AccountID" => 9407
    "year" => 2019
    "month" => "November"
    "received" => 36
    "analyzed" => 138
    "failed" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "AccountID" => 1975
    "year" => 2020
    "month" => "April"
    "received" => 230
    "analyzed" => 1
    "failed" => 7      ]
```

until now I've tried the following code, which I use to merge 2 arrays together. this i repeat for the other arrays, merging 2 at once. But it is delivering wrong values. Probably because it is only comparing if the key exist and not also the value of it.

```
       foreach ($received_list as $key => $received) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $analyzed_list)) {
            $merged[$key] = array_merge($received_list[$key], $analyzed_list[$key]);
        } else {
            $merged[$key] = array_merge($received_list[$key], ['analyzed' => 0]);
        }
       }
      foreach ($analyzed_list as $key => $received) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $received_list)) {
            $merged[$key] = array_merge($analyzed_list[$key], $received_list[$key]);
        } else {
            $merged[$key] = array_merge($analyzed_list[$key], ['received' => 0]);
        }
      }
```

Any kind of help is much appreciated!

Comment: Post your arrays as var_export instead. Nobody will retype all your arrays to work with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best performing one but looks like it works

The sample;

```
    $first = [
        ['AccountID' => 9407, 'year' => 2019, 'month' => 'November', 'received' => 36],
        ['AccountID' => 1975, 'year' => 2019, 'month' => 'November', 'received' => 230],
    ];
    $second = [
        ['AccountID' => 9407, 'year' => 2019, 'month' => 'November', 'analyzed' => 138],
        ['AccountID' => 1975, 'year' => 2019, 'month' => 'April', 'analyzed' => 1],
    ];
    $third = [
        ['AccountID' => 9407, 'year' => 2019, 'month' => 'November', 'failed' => 1],
        ['AccountID' => 1975, 'year' => 2020, 'month' => 'April', 'failed' => 7],
    ];
```

The code;

```
    return collect([$first, $second, $third])
        ->flatten(1)
        ->transform(function ($group) {
            $group['id'] = $group['AccountID'] . '-' . $group['year'] . '-' . $group['month'];

            return $group;
        })
        ->groupBy('id')
        ->transform(function (Collection $subGroup) {
            $merge = [];

            $subGroup->transform(function ($sub) use (&$merge) {
                unset($sub['id']);
                $merge = array_merge($sub, $merge);

                return $merge;
            });

            return $subGroup->last();
        })
        ->values()
        ->toArray();
```

json response;

```
[{"AccountID":9407,"year":2019,"month":"November","failed":1,"analyzed":138,"received":36},{"AccountID":1975,"year":2019,"month":"November","received":230},{"AccountID":1975,"year":2019,"month":"April","analyzed":1},{"AccountID":1975,"year":2020,"month":"April","failed":7}]
```